# Fix Sidebar in the same row as other elements

Tags: html, css

So basically I have a sidebar which I wan't to be fixed in my page and have only the other column in my row be scrollable.

I tried changing the `position` css attribute of the element, but then the original content would be squished into the first column.

A demo of what I have is available here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3vvh4ux/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4" role="sidebar">
                    <div class="diamond"><span>RS</span></div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="brief">
                        Text here...
                    </div>
                    <form class="search">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="github"><a href="#">Github</a></li>
                        <li class="twitter"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li class="stackoverflow"><a href="#">StackOverflow</a></li>
                        <li class="linkedin"><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-8" role="content">
                    <h1 class="title">Title</h1><div class="horizontal-rule"></div>
                    <nav class="subnav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> /
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> /
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> /
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which element you want to have fixed, but you could use this method:

```
<div id="id">
Content of the div
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#id {
position: fixed;
left: 30px; // or whatever you want
top: 100px; // or whatever you want
}
```

I hope this helped for you!